# Dois ou mais ScrollViews com background na mesma BoxLabel com Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, gui

Estou criando uma GUI simples com Kivy no Python 3x e tenho tido problemas em colocar dois ScrollViews na mesma BoxLabel.

Da forma que coloquei, no código anexado, os itens ficam assim:
[Com ScrollViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHU2M.png)

Mas o esperado era que ficassem assim:
[Sem ScrollViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFcRK.jpg)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from utils import Grade
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

kivy.require('1.9.1')

Builder.load_string("""
<BackgroundBoxLayout>:
  canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
      source: 'data/backgrounds/title.png'
<GridLayout>:
  canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
      source: 'data/backgrounds/label.png'
""")


class DropFile(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DropFile, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # aparência do botão
        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.background_normal = 'data/icons/pdf_icon_normal.png'
        self.background_down = 'data/icons/pdf_icon_down.png'

    # define o que ocorre quando arquivo é solto no local indicado
    def on_dropfile(self):
        if self.collide_point(*Window.mouse_pos) and not self.disabled:
            self.disabled = True


class BackgroundBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MultiLineLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MultiLineLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_size = self.size
        self.halign = 'center'
        self.pos_hint = {'top': 0.5}
        self.bind(size=self.on_size)
        self.bind(text=self.on_text_changed)

    def on_size(self, widget, size):
        self.text_size = size[0], None
        self.texture_update()
        if self.size_hint_y is None and self.size_hint_x is not None:
            self.height = max(self.texture_size[1], self.line_height)
        elif self.size_hint_x is None and self.size_hint_y is not None:
            self.width = self.texture_size[0]

    def on_text_changed(self, widget, text):
        print(len(text))
        self.halign = 'left'
        if len(text) > 300:
            self.on_size(self, self.size)
            self.font_size = 12
            self.pos_hint = {'top': 1}
        elif len(text) > 280:
            self.pos_hint = {'top': 0.6}
        elif len(text) > 240:
            self.pos_hint = {'top': 0.6}
        elif len(text) > 100:
            self.halign = 'center'
            self.pos_hint = {'top': 0.7}
        else:
            self.halign = 'center'
            self.pos_hint = {'top': 0.5}


class SimulaReforma(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SimulaReforma, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.handledrops)

        # Layouts
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        disciplinas_label = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, 1))
        status_label = BackgroundBoxLayout(size_hint=(1, None))
        tittle_label = BackgroundBoxLayout(size_hint=(1, 0.2))

        # Tittle Label
        tittle_label.add_widget(Image(source='data/icons/ufs_icon.png', size_hint=(0.1, 0.8), pos_hint={'top': 0.9}))
        tittle_label.add_widget(Label(text='[b]Simulador de mudança de grade para cursos do DCOMP[/b]',
                                      font_size=20, markup=True, color=get_color_from_hex("#000000")))

        # Status label
        drop_button = DropFile(pos_hint={'right': 1.5})
        status_label.add_widget(drop_button)
        self.status = MultiLineLabel(text='[b]ARRASTE O HISTÓRICO GERADO PELO SIGAA PARA O BOTÃO AO LADO[/b]',
                                     size_hint=(1, None), markup=True, color=get_color_from_hex("#000000"))
        status_label.add_widget(self.status)

        # Disciplinas label
        self.grid1 = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        self.grid1.bind(minimum_height=self.grid1.setter('height'))
        for i in range(50):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            self.grid1.add_widget(btn)
        self.grid2 = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        self.grid2.bind(minimum_height=self.grid2.setter('height'))
        for i in range(50):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            self.grid2.add_widget(btn)

        cursadas = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None))
        cursadas.add_widget(self.grid1)
        nao_cursadas = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None))
        nao_cursadas.add_widget(self.grid2)

        disciplinas_label.add_widget(cursadas)
        disciplinas_label.add_widget(nao_cursadas)

        # box add labels
        box.add_widget(tittle_label)
        box.add_widget(disciplinas_label)
        box.add_widget(status_label)

        return box

    def handledrops(self, *args):
        self.status.text = "[b]PROCESSANDO HISTÓRICO...[/b]"
        # instancia as grades
        self.nova_grade = Grade('novas_grades/Eng_Comp.csv')
        self.grade_atual = Grade(args[1].decode("utf-8"))

        self.status.text = "[b]REALIZANDO EQUIVALÊNCIAS...[/b]"
        # realiza as equivalências da nova grade com base na sua grade atual
        resultado_equivalencia = self.nova_grade.realizar_equivalencias(self.grade_atual.grade["GERAL"])
        self.status.text = resultado_equivalencia

        # printa as disciplinas já cursadas
        label = Label(text=("[b]DISCIPLINAS CURSADAS:[/b]\n\n" + self.nova_grade.disciplinas_cursadas()),
                      size_hint_y=None,
                      color=get_color_from_hex('#000000'), markup=True)
        before = label._label.render()
        label.text_size = (300, None)
        after = label._label.render()
        label.height = (after[1] / before[1]) * before[1]
        self.grid1.add_widget(label)

        label = Label(text=("[b]DISCIPLINAS NÃO CURSADAS:[/b]\n\n" + self.nova_grade.disciplinas_faltam()),
                      size_hint_y=None, markup=True)
        before = label._label.render()
        label.text_size = (300, None)
        after = label._label.render()
        label.height = (after[1] / before[1]) * before[1]
        self.grid2.add_widget(label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimulaReforma().run()
```

Caso seja necessário, o projeto completo está disponível em: github.com/arielrodrigues/dcomp.ufs.reforma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de um tempo debugando percebi que quando removo as imagens dos retângulos do GridLayout e do BoxLayout e ponho cores no lugar, ficando assim:

```
<BackgroundBoxLayout>:
  canvas.before:
    Color:
      rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Rectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
<GridLayout>:
  canvas.before:
    Color:
      rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Rectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
```

O resultado bate com o esperado (na iamgem, removi os botões. Eles estavam ali só por conta do debug): [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, o problema parece ser um bug na API que estava sendo causado pela imagem no background.